# jQuery How to pass variables in jQuery.css({})

Tags: jquery

When using this script the console returns an error **"SyntaxError: missing } after property list"** How do I pass *vscroll* variable into .css.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            var vscroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            jQuery('#logotext').css({
                "transform": "translate(0px, "vscroll/2+"px)"
            });
        });  
    </script>
```

Comment: You miss a `+`.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory there is a +

Comment: `"translate(0px, "vscroll/2+"px)"` => `"translate(0px, "+vscroll/2+"px)"`

Answer (score 1):

You missed adding the `+` sign before `vscroll/2` in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var vscroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        jQuery('#logotext').css({
            "transform": "translate(0px, "+vscroll/2+"px)"
        });
    });  
</script>
```